# Failed on starting Spring Tool Suite when I change XMx

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, vmargs

I am trying to change and increase the default -Xmx768m to -Xmx1024 in STS.ini. However, on startup I get an error saying "Failed to create the JVM".

If I revert it back to 768 it works fine. Any idea as to what am I doing wrong and how can I improve the performance of STS?

Here is the configuration

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222

-product
com.springsource.sts.ide

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: I think JVM failed to allocate that maximum size to the heap. Does running fewer processes to free up the RAM help? Otherwise, I think your hardware might need to be upgraded, but I'm only guessing here.

Comment: Well there is 4gig of RAM on my machine. Task Manager shows half of it as unutilised.

Comment: Can you post the complete configuration, including the other sizes? Also, is that -Xmx1024 or -Xmx1024m? (Not sure what is the default if you don't specify the "m").

Comment: Posted the configuration. its 1024m.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to attach the jvisualvm profiler tool (can be found in the bin folder of your jdk). If anything the tool will give you info about the jvm and its resource usage.

Be careful to use the tool that comes with the jdk you use for STS (most likely the one in JAVA_HOME but not necessarily).

Mind you that on a 32bit OS the JVM will never be able to get more than 1.6 GB of memory. If you have other software already in that same JVM as STS, jvisualvm will list them in the left side panel.